# Apache Nifi and cassandra4.0

Tags: cassandra, etl, apache-nifi, data-warehouse

Our company use Cassandra 4.0 as our DWH and we are trying to change our ETL tool to nifi.

But nifi only supports Cassandra 3.0 which Cassandra supports only python 2.7.

Is there any way to use nifi with Cassandra 4.0?
what open source ETL tool would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I will provide some information that may be helpful. It looks like there is a request for using Cassandra 4.0 in a future version of NiFi, as a ticket was just submitted. If it were to get enough noise, then I think they might add it in. https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI/issues/NIFI-10285